# Grails transactions: duplicate data where there shouldn't be any

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, grails, postgresql-9.3

I'm not sure where in the whole Grails / Hibernate / Tomcat / Database stack the root of all evil lies. My problem is this: I have a service (transactional, of course) that is used to search for so called (medical) cases. Every case is attached to exactly one patient.

Here's the simplified relationship (I omitted all the meta data around that).

```
class Case {
    static belongsTo = [casePatient: CasePatient]
}

class CasePatient {
    static hasMany = [cases: Case]
}
```

Now, when a new case is saved, the service first checks if one already exists and if so, simply returns. To save a case you obviously need some case related data and some patient related data which is provided. If the case does not exist the service then tries to find the patient in order to prevent duplicates. From the title you can now probably guess my problem.

For whatever diabolic reason, I happened to come across the same patient 99 times (as one extreme example). All the fields that are used for identifiying a record match 100%. Something that should be impossible due to the search. It doesn't happen all the time, it's rare, but it happens and it sucks. Once there's more than one patient returned from the search the service is designed to cry out loud like a little kid and throws around itself with exceptions. There can only be on after all.

What's odd: timestamps on the database indicate that the records have been created exactly 30 seconds apart which resulted in a total timespan of 50 minutes where this mess happened. It looks like for 50 minutes the transactions haven't been persisted to the database or otherwise I have no explanation why the search wouldn't find anything.

The webservice is used by our own software that tries to upload data. It performs a search itself and only if nothing is found, a request for a new case is created.

Unfortunately I have no debug logs so I can't see what's happening on the server. I've setup a test installation to get some, but since I don't really know how to provoke it... All I can do is wait and hope that it'll happen at some point.

Anyway, I'm at a loss. I have no idea where to start looking. From the service code it seems impossible to me (and a collegue) that this is happening. Do any of you have any suggestions on how to nail this sucker down?

Software used:

- Grails 2.4.4 (and 2.5.0 as well)
- Tomcat 7
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-1~deb7u1)
- PostgreSQL 9.3
- Debian 7.8 (wheezy)

Comment: From the sound of it, perhaps the transaction isolation level is preventing "dirty" records from being returned in your search and thus not seen as a match while they are in process of being saved. I'd recommend you adjust the isolation level to: `defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ` in your `DataSource.groovy` for your datasource `properties`. See if the problem disappears at that point. You also might consider manually flushing `.save(flush: true)` when you do your saves as well.

Comment: `flush: true` is already set everywhere. Yes, dirty reads are prevented and in this situation it cannot be changed. But I managed to develop a theory already which I only need to prove somehow. If it works out, I'll answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the database. For some as of yet unknown reason there's a contention somewhere in the database that prevents the INSERT statements for my cases and patients to go through in a timely fashion. The Grails service waits for the statement to finish, but the client that creates the case times out after, you have three guesses and the first two don't count, 30 seconds. After that it simply continues with the next file (actions are triggered on a file basis), doing the same thing again, and very likely for the same patient.

While the first INSERT transaction is still waiting to be processed, the second request won't find that data and decides to create a new case and a new patient itself, ultimately adding another INSERT to the queue. In this extreme case this happened over a timespan of 50 seconds which resulted in 99 save-case requests all being flushed once the knot on the database had burst.

I verified this thesis by artifically creating a shared lock on the patient table that allows reading but not writing. That means all the SELECTs worked fine and didn't find anything. Only when it came to INSERT data the lock blocked the execution. I waited a few minutes to release the lock and then I found myself with duplicate entries where there shouldn't be any.

While I still need to figure out where this lock comes from, I solved this issue by setting a statement timeout for that save-session at the beginning of the service method. I have a utility method for that.

```
static void setStatementTimeout(def session, int milliseconds) {
    log.trace "->setStatementTimeout: <milliseconds: $milliseconds>"

    def query = session.createSQLQuery("set statement_timeout to $milliseconds")
    query.executeUpdate()
}
```

The `session` is obtained from `sessionFactory.currentSession`.

Now the database cancels the request after 15 seconds and the whole save request is aborted.